# Why was this question comment-locked?

Tags: discussion, support, comments, moderators, comment-lock

[Why are (return) and return different?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62804051/why-are-return-and-return-different)

The comments were moved to this chat room:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217505/discussion-on-question-by-neko-musume-why-are-return-and-return-different

I don't see anything there that would warrant a comment lock.  Granted, there might be some comments that were deleted before the move to chat, but this doesn't seem like a particularly controversial topic.

If this is about forcing everyone into chat, then why don't we just fix the "move to chat" functionality so that it does the right thing?

Comment: Well, given we can trust the mods here on SO it is safe to assume something warranted that action. Waiting 11 hours for the comment lock to expire doesn't seem to problematic. Why would we need to spend a meta post on it to attract attention to a case that seems peacefully solved for now.

Comment: I actually have a lot of problems with the way the comment system is moderated nowadays.  I suppose I could have written a larger post, but why don't we just focus on this specific issue for now.  Also, moderator trust is hardly a given.

Comment: We trust the moderators less nowadays? Oh, you removed the "nowadays" from your previous comment. Changes the tone a bit. But still, I think that trust in our elected volunteers is generally warranted. They do make mistakes, and we are not always going to agree on everything... but unless an action is particularly disruptive, it's not worth arguing over every disagreement.

Comment: Please don't make this about trust in the moderators. Even people who are trustworthy can make mistakes, and Robert or anyone else is entitled to ask a question about our rationale without even assuming that we made a mistake. Transparency is good. I personally don't see why Sam thought it necessary to lock the post, either, but he and I don't always see eye-to-eye when it comes to moderating comments. Nevertheless, I still generally trust his judgment.

Comment: Locking comments for 23 hours is ridiculous. Move the comments to chat, but leave comments unlocked so that further request for clarification to the questioner can be made. Prime example [Why can not assign memory address number to C++ pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63066309/why-can-not-assign-memory-address-number-to-c-pointer) a comment requesting the hardware type would be warranted since it appears the question is related to a microcontroller, but that clarification cannot be requested because the comments were locked for 23 hours. Counterproductive.